# Passing -D System Properties to App Created with Gradle Application Plugin

Tags: gradle, environment-variables

I'm using the Gradle Application plugin which is generating a shell script for me.  I need to be able to pass system properties to my application via the shell script.  For example, this works...

```
java -Dvar1=test -jar myApp.jar arg1
```

But this doesn't work

```
./myApp -Dvar1=test arg1
```

Where myApp is the shell script.  My application also accepts arguments from the command line, which work fine.  What's happening is the `-D` bit is being passed in as the first argument to my app when the first argument should be `arg1`.  Is there something in my gradle config I can do to make this work? Or what?

Comment: I'm not aware of a config option. If there is one, you'll find it in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) or [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: If there isn't a config option, any idea how to make this work?  Will my app just have to read those in as arguments and add them as env var's manually?  Seems backwards.  I know how I could modify the shell script to do this manually.  But I need it to keep being generated.

Comment: These aren't env vars but system properties. If there is no config option, you'll have to post-process the script or generate your own script.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question to refer to them as system properties.

Comment: For this to work, the shell script would have to determine which command line arguments are JVM options (such as `-D`) and which aren't. The shell script generated by the application plugin can't do that.

Comment: You can use the environment variable JAVA_OPTS to set -D system properties. Also there is a specific environment variable name based on the name of the script. For example MYAPP_OPTS in your example. You can find it when you open the generated application shell script file.